# Appending code to a method

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I'm trying to append some code to a method of an XMLHttpRequest object, but something is not working. The relevant code:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
var newOpen = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
    alert( "[debug info]" );
    this.oldOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
}
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = newOpen;
```

When open() is called, the alert goes off, but the original function is not called. Why is this?

For reference, it's part of a GreaseMonkey script supposed to listen to XHR traffic. The full script follows:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest;

var startTracing = function () {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.uniqueID = function() {
        // each XMLHttpRequest gets assigned a unique ID and memorizes it 
        //  in the "uniqueIDMemo" property
        if (!this.uniqueIDMemo) {
            this.uniqueIDMemo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        }
        return this.uniqueIDMemo;
    }

    // backup original "open" function reference
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    var oOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

    var newOpen = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
        alert("open: " + method + "," + url + "," + async + "," + user + "," + password );
        this.oldOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
    }

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = newOpen;

}

startTracing();
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because `open()` is implemented using native code, not JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Do you know of any other way of knowing when an XHR is open()ed? FireBug does it, so I assume that it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this, which is essentially a rework of your code, and it worked just fine. Here is my whole greasemonkey script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           sof
// @namespace      taylor.kelly.sof
// @description    Stack overflow testing
// @include        http://localhost:8080/tests/sof.html
// ==/UserScript==

var XMLHttpRequest = unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest;
var startTracing = function () {
    // backup original "open" function reference
    var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
        alert("open: " + method + "," + url + "," + async + "," + user + "," + password );
        open.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

startTracing();
```

There is a timing issue when greasemonkey scripts load. You may have to wait for window.onload to fire up your XHTTPRequest on your test page.

May I also suggest that your uniqueId scheme will probably have some collisions. Using new Date().getTime() in conjunction with Math.random would reduce those to nearly 0. Something like:

`new Date().getTime() + '' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)`